# Why are no Microsoft-Windows-Power-Troubleshooter events logged?

Tags: windows-10, wake-on-lan, event-log

for a script a need to read the Microsoft-Windows-Power-Troubleshooter events (wake time, wake duration, wake source) but there is no event registered from Microsoft-Windows-Power-Troubleshooter on the system log.
I tested this with 3 PC (a VM, a laptop and a Desktop), could it depends on a group policy?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: to find the Microsoft-Windows-Power-Troubleshooter events I use
"Get-EventLog -LogName System -Source "*Power" | Where-Object -Property Source -like Troubleshooter" but not values are returned: to my understanding it means that Microsoft-Windows-Power-Troubleshooter events are not logged from windows. How I can solve this?

Comment: Did you look in Event Viewer and filter for Power events?

Comment: @theasker - [Edit] your question instead of putting vital information in a temporary comment